# Mockito doReturn making list immutable

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to test a method like this:

```
public getIndustries(int countryId) {
    var industryList = industryControllerService.getIndustriesByCountryId(countryId);
    ...
    industryList.add(new IndustryCategory(otherIndustry));
}
```

in my test I have:

```
List<IndustryCategory> expected = List.of(industryCategory1, industryCategory2);
doReturn(expected).when(industryControllerService).getIndustriesByCountryId(anyInt());
...
```

But for some reason the industryList is returned by Mockito as an immutable collection, so the add operation throws a UnsupportedOperationException.

How can I change it so that the list is a normal one that can be edited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List.of` returns an immutable list. Try copying it into an ArrayList: `expected = new ArrayList<>(List.of(...))`.